# Bound for Inner Product Between Matrix Vector and Vector i.e $Ax$ and $x$

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, matrices, vectors, inner-products

Assume $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$ is invertible, what kind of assumptions on $A$ do I need to have a bound of the form

$$c_1 \|x\|^2\leq \langle Ax,x\rangle \leq c_2 \|x\|^2,~~\text{for any} ~x\in \mathbb{R}^n$$

for some $c_1,c_2$ constants.

Comment: Is $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ the dot product or an arbitrary inner product?

Comment: dot product it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is true for arbitrary $A \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$. You don't even need $A$ to be invertible. Any inner product $\langle x , y \rangle$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ can be expressed as $y^T S x$ for a symmetric, positive-definite matrix $S \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$. So
$$
|\langle Ax , x \rangle| = |x^T S (Ax)| \leq \|x\|\|(SA)x\|
$$ But linear maps like $x \mapsto (SA)x$, composed of matrix-vector products, are **bounded maps** i.e. $\|(SA)x\| \leq C\|x\|$ for some $C \geq 0$. Hence,
$$
|\langle Ax , x \rangle| \leq \|x\|(C\|x\|) = C \|x\|^2
$$

Comment: How about if $A=B+B_h$ with $\|B_h\|=O(h)$, can we still get this result for constant $C$?

Comment: Yes. The form of the matrix does not matter. If you want, for any matrix $M \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, you can take $C = \sqrt{n}\max_{1 \leq i, j \leq n}|M_{i,j}|$ to get $\|Mx\| \leq C\|x\|$.

Comment: Ok so let $A+B_h$ be invertible, then there exists a $C$ independent of $h$ such that $\langle (A+B_h)^{-1}x, x \rangle \leq C \|x\|^2 $ ? With $\|B_h\|=O(h)$

Comment: @Flows. The question is different now. Your new question is asking whether you can find a constant $C$ independent of the matrix itself. That is not true. The constant $C$ certainly depends on the matrix elements $M_{i, j}$.

Comment: yeh and I just got counter example for my setup. Thanks anywho